# How to exclude feed items having a mobile number in yahoo pipes

Tags: regex, pipe, yahoo, yahoo-pipes

1. I need to exclude feed items having a mobile number in them. Mobile numbers are 10 digits long or 12 digits longs with a +  sign before it. I have used filter module but am unable to find the regex. The mobile numbers are like 9876543210 or +919876543210
2. I also need to exclude feed items having more than 1 @ symbol 
   feed sample: @stack @overflow blah blah

Answer (score 0):

1. A regex matching such numbers could be `\+\d{10}(?:\d\d)?\b`.
2. A regex for a string with 2 or more `@` is `@[^@]*@`

To check if any of the regex match you could use something like:

```
\+\d{10}(?:\d\d)?\b|@[^@]*@
```

Use whatever logic you have in pipes to invert the match result and exclude posts if matched. Or you could use negative lookahead like so:

```
(?s)^(?!.*?\+\d{10}(?:\d\d)?\b|[^@]*@[^@]*@)
```

*(Not sure if all those regex features are supported in pipes.)*